# how to add two or more responses data in same array in react js

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I have created some tickets..Now I need to display the ticket details based on the seat which i clicked.I have to fetch the two different ticket status responses and I need to merge them to get all the tickets.
And I need to display the ticket details based on seat number.By using react I have set the state of one response now I need to append the data from another response in same array.

Comment: Please add some code to your question, your attempt to tackle this issue.

Comment: `ADD CODE ` .Community cannot help you without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spread operator [...]
Like:

```
const array1 = [item,item,item];
const array2 = [item,item,item];

const mergedArray = [...array1, ...array2];
```